# Android java Add a textView

Tags: java, android

I have a java file that its setContentView is to another java file...

Here is the first java file

```
    package dalton.metzler.occupied;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PlayActivity extends Activity{

    Play ourView;

    LinearLayout linear;
    TextView text;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ourView = new Play(this);
        setContentView(ourView);
    }



}
```

And here is the file thats linking to it as the set contentview there is not speical code you need to look at just showing so you can see what it is.

And see exactly what i mean about the text thing i am trying to do

```
    package dalton.metzler.occupied;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;


    public class Play extends View {

    Bitmap gBall1, gBall2, gBall3, gBall4, gBall5, gBall6, gBall7, gBall8, gBall9, gBall10, gBall11, gBall12, gBall13;

    float changingY, changingY2, changingY3, changingY4, changingY5, changingY6, changingY7, changingY8, changingY9, changingY10, changingY11, changingY12, changingY13;


    public Play(Context context) {
        super(context);


        gBall1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
        gBall2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
        gBall3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
        gBall4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
        changingY = 0;
        changingY2 = -110;
        changingY3 = -220;
        changingY4 = -330;
        changingY5 = -440;
        changingY6 = -550;
        changingY7 = -660;
        changingY8 = -770;
        changingY9 = -880;
        changingY10 = -990;
        changingY11 = -1100;
        changingY12 = -1210;
        changingY13 = -1320;

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall1, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall2, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY2, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall3, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY3, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY4, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY5, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY6, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY7, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY8, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY9, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY10, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY11, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY12, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall4, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY13, null);
    if (changingY < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY += 5;

    }else{
        changingY = -600;
    }
    if (changingY2 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY2 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY2 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY3 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY3 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY3 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY4 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY4 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY4 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY5 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY5 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY5 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY6 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY6 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY6 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY7 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY7 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY7 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY8 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY8 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY8 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY9 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY9 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY9 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY10 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY10 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY10 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY11 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY11 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY11 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY12 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY12 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY12 = -600;
    }
    if (changingY13 < canvas.getHeight()){
        changingY13 += 5;

    }else{
        changingY13 = -600;
    }
    invalidate();   
    }       
}
```

How can i add text to the app? Like a textview but not in the xml because i can't do this    (i think)
I want to add like the text:  Score: 0 to the screen

Comment: You should use arrays instead of mainting long lists of variables.  Such an approach allows you to use for loops to manipulate all of the elements in your arrays

Comment: You need to learn the basics of programming.  There's a good [tutorial on arrays](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-arrays/) a tutsplus.  You should probably speed read through all the chapters just so you know what is possible, then study each chapter as you use  it in your program.  Knowing the correct techniques will help you write efficient and concise code.  Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you cannot added another view to your custom View as it extends the View class. You will need to extend a viewgroup class to add other views.

Create a linear layout and add the play view and the textview to that and set the linear layout in the setContentView function.

If you just need to draw text on playview, there is the canvas.drawText function.

I think your drawText method is wrong. Try this.

```
    Paint orangePaint = new Paint();
    orangePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawText("test", 50, 50, orangePaint);
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi, i did this canvas.drawText("test", 50, 50, Color.BLACK, 0, null); in my protect void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { method and i got a force close

Comment: Update your question with the stack trace. Lets see whats wrong.

Comment: Error message you get in the logcat. Its in Eclipse->ShowView->Logcat.

Comment: blessenm, how can i assign a id or something to it?  so if i hit a button and the text is 1 it will turn it to 2

Comment: You will need to draw the text on top of it. You should actually consider using a frame layout instead of trying to do everything in a single view.